# Add fields to woocommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add one or two fields on cart page. I want to take my users preferred delivery time.
for example I am selling cakes and want users preferred date and time when they want it.

**I want it on carts page not on checkout page.**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table', 'custom_timing_fields' );
function custom_timing_fields() {
     echo "something like input or select box here";   
}
```

Comment: Great, but how did you registered that with the email order notification?

Comment: I am working on it. I think by registering this values in woocommerce session.